# find pair of rows with largest value difference in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a large dataframe containing the x,y,z coordinates of a surface.
i am looking to find the pair of rows with the largest slope between them (dz/sqrt(dx^2+dy^2))

```
maxGrad = 0
currentGrad = 0
height = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
  for j in range(i+1,len(df)):
      height = abs(df.z.iloc[j]-df.z.iloc[i])
      distance = math.sqrt((df.x.iloc[j]-df.x.iloc[i])**2+(df.y.iloc[j]-df.y.iloc[i])**2)
      currentGrad = height/distance
      if currentGrad > maxGrad:
          maxGrad = currentGrad
          maxCoorPair = [df.x.iloc[i],df.y.iloc[i],df.x.iloc[j],df.y.iloc[j]]
print(maxGrad, maxCoorPair)
```

However this is not very elegant and the run time is very long due to the nested for loop.

How can i do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x":[1,5,3],
        "y":[12,10,13],
        "z":[4,4,1],
    }
)
```

let's define a function which takes a vector of length n, and returns a *n x n* numpy array where the element in row *i* and column *j* is given by the difference of the *i*th and *j*th element in the vector

```
def d(vector):
    return vector.apply(lambda x: x-vector).values
```

For example

```
d(df["x"])
```

gives

```
array([[ 0, -4, -2],
       [ 4,  0,  2],
       [ 2, -2,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

Plug this method into your formula like so, to perform calcs for all pairs of coordinates at once

```
slopes = d(df["z"])/np.sqrt(np.square(d(df["x"])) + np.square(d(df["y"])))
```

`slopes` looks like this

```
array([[        nan,  0.        ,  1.34164079],
       [ 0.        ,         nan,  0.83205029],
       [-1.34164079, -0.83205029,         nan]])
```

Note that in the formula, the absolute value of *dz* is not used.  This is deliberate in order to not end up with answers of the form "(a,b) and (b,a)".

We can then use `numpy.nanmax` which calculates the maximum of an array, ignoring `nan` values, and use `numpy.where` to pull out the rows and columns which match the maximum found

```
cols, rows = np.where(slopes==np.nanmax(slopes))
```

We can then zip these up to get tuples of coordinates

```
list(zip(rows, cols))
```

which gives us `[(0, 2)]`

So the largest slope is between the coordinates in rows 0 and 2

Comment: works as advertised. awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As often it depends of the size of the problem.

Lets do some investigations

**Conclusions:**

Numpy arrays are faster than even if no Numpy function is used. .

The use of numpy functions still accelerates but at the expense of:

- some initialization time
- a loss of precision which leads to warnings

## Investigations

### init

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
```

```
Run = namedtuple('run', ['order', 'npa', 'df'])
def generate(maxorder):
    run_list = []
    for n in range(1, maxorder + 1):
        order = n
        npa = np.random.random(size=(10**n, 3))
        run_list.append(Run(order, npa, pd.DataFrame(npa, columns=list('xyz'))))
        
    return run_list
```

```
runs = generate(5)
```

### tools

```
from functools import wraps
import time
```

```
def timeit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kw)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"{func.__name__}  {(end_time - start_time) * 1000} ms")
        return result
    return timed
```

```
def prints(f, data, max_order):
    for order,npa,df in runs[:max_order]:
        print()
        print("Order:", order)
        maxGrad, maxCoorPair = f(df if data == 'df' else npa)
        print("maxGrad:", maxGrad)
        print("Pair:")
        print(maxCoorPair)
```

## Solutions

#### original solution

```
@timeit
def sol_original(df):
    maxGrad = 0
    currentGrad = 0
    height = 0
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(df)):
            height = abs(df.z.iloc[j]-df.z.iloc[i])
            distance = math.sqrt((df.x.iloc[j]-df.x.iloc[i])**2+(df.y.iloc[j]-df.y.iloc[i])**2)
            currentGrad = height/distance
            if currentGrad > maxGrad:
                maxGrad = currentGrad
                maxCoorPair = [(df.x.iloc[i],df.y.iloc[i]),(df.x.iloc[j],df.y.iloc[j])]
    return maxGrad, maxCoorPair
```

```
prints(sol_original, 'df', 3)
```

```
Order: 1
sol_original  2.979278564453125 ms
maxGrad: 4.274082602280762
Pair:
[(0.08217955028694601, 0.9160537098844143), (0.2396284679279188, 0.8196073645585937)]

Order: 2
sol_original  264.29247856140137 ms
maxGrad: 167.5282986999116
Pair:
[(0.09926115331767238, 0.7497707080285022), (0.09615387652529517, 0.7469231082687531)]

Order: 3
sol_original  24213.2625579834 ms
maxGrad: 1246.4073209631038
Pair:
[(0.8285207768494603, 0.016839864860434428), (0.8285102753052541, 0.016228726039262287)]
```

#### solution numpy1.0 : substitute np array to df

```
@timeit
def sol_numpy10(npa):
    maxGrad = 0
    currentGrad = 0
    height = 0
    
    for i in range(len(npa)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(npa)):
            height = abs(npa[j][2]-npa[i][2])
            distance = math.sqrt((npa[j][0]-npa[i][0])**2+(npa[j][1]-npa[i][1])**2)
            currentGrad = height/distance
            if currentGrad > maxGrad:
                maxGrad = currentGrad
                maxCoorPair = [(npa[i][0],npa[i][1]),(npa[j][0],npa[j][1])]
    return maxGrad, maxCoorPair
```

```
prints(sol_numpy10, 'np', 3)
```

```
Order: 1
sol_numpy10  0.0 ms
maxGrad: 4.274082602280762
Pair:
[(0.08217955028694601, 0.9160537098844143), (0.2396284679279188, 0.8196073645585937)]

Order: 2
sol_numpy10  13.963699340820312 ms
maxGrad: 167.5282986999116
Pair:
[(0.09926115331767238, 0.7497707080285022), (0.09615387652529517, 0.7469231082687531)]

Order: 3
sol_numpy10  998.3282089233398 ms
maxGrad: 1246.4073209631038
Pair:
[(0.8285207768494603, 0.016839864860434428), (0.8285102753052541, 0.016228726039262287)]
```

#### solution numpy1.1: idem numpy1.0 and optimize i coordinates

```
@timeit
def sol_numpy11(npa):
    maxGrad = 0
    currentGrad = 0
    height = 0
    
    for i in range(len(npa)):
        xi,yi,zi = npa[i]
        for j in range(i+1,len(npa)):
            height = abs(npa[j][2]-zi)
            distance = math.sqrt((npa[j][0]-xi)**2+(npa[j][1]-yi)**2)
            currentGrad = height/distance
            if currentGrad > maxGrad:
                maxGrad = currentGrad
                maxCoorPair = [(xi,yi),(npa[j][0],npa[j][1])]
    return(maxGrad, maxCoorPair)
```

```
prints(sol_numpy11, 'np', 3)
```

```
Order: 1
sol_numpy11  0.0 ms
maxGrad: 4.274082602280762
Pair:
[(0.08217955028694601, 0.9160537098844143), (0.2396284679279188, 0.8196073645585937)]

Order: 2
sol_numpy11  10.002613067626953 ms
maxGrad: 167.5282986999116
Pair:
[(0.09926115331767238, 0.7497707080285022), (0.09615387652529517, 0.7469231082687531)]

Order: 3
sol_numpy11  771.9049453735352 ms
maxGrad: 1246.4073209631038
Pair:
[(0.8285207768494603, 0.016839864860434428), (0.8285102753052541, 0.016228726039262287)]
```

#### solution numpy1.2; idem numpy1.1 and optimize j coordinates

```
@timeit
def sol_numpy12(npa):
    maxGrad = 0
    currentGrad = 0
    height = 0
    
    for i in range(len(npa)):
        xi,yi,zi = npa[i]
        for j in range(i+1,len(npa)):
            xj,yj,zj = npa[j]
            height = abs(zj-zi)
            distance = math.sqrt((xj-xi)**2+(yj-yi)**2)
            currentGrad = height/distance
            if currentGrad > maxGrad:
                maxGrad = currentGrad
                maxCoorPair = [(xi,yi),(xj,yj)]
    return(maxGrad, maxCoorPair)
```

```
prints(sol_numpy12, 'np', 3)
```

```
Order: 1
sol_numpy12  0.0 ms
maxGrad: 4.274082602280762
Pair:
[(0.08217955028694601, 0.9160537098844143), (0.2396284679279188, 0.8196073645585937)]

Order: 2
sol_numpy12  8.97526741027832 ms
maxGrad: 167.5282986999116
Pair:
[(0.09926115331767238, 0.7497707080285022), (0.09615387652529517, 0.7469231082687531)]

Order: 3
sol_numpy12  1075.1206874847412 ms
maxGrad: 1246.4073209631038
Pair:
[(0.8285207768494603, 0.016839864860434428), (0.8285102753052541, 0.016228726039262287)]
```

#### solution numpy2.0

Riley's answer

```
def d(vector):
    return vector.apply(lambda x: x-vector).values

@timeit
def sol_numpy20(df):
    slopes = np.abs(d(df["z"]))/np.sqrt(np.square(d(df["x"])) + np.square(d(df["y"])))
    maxGrad = np.nanmax(slopes)
    ind1, ind2 = np.where(slopes==maxGrad)
    maxCoorPair = [df.iloc[ind2]]
    return maxGrad, maxCoorPair
```

```
prints(sol_numpy20, 'df', 4)
```

```
Order: 1
10
sol_numpy20  6.981372833251953 ms
maxGrad: 4.274082602280762
Pair:
[          x         y         z
6  0.239628  0.819607  0.867972
5  0.082180  0.916054  0.078804]

Order: 2
100
sol_numpy20  42.88601875305176 ms
maxGrad: 167.5282986999116
Pair:
[           x         y         z
95  0.096154  0.746923  0.135159
45  0.099261  0.749771  0.841247]

Order: 3
1000


<ipython-input-201-ce6f8e091e1b>:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  slopes = np.abs(d(df["z"]))/np.sqrt(np.square(d(df["x"])) + np.square(d(df["y"])))
<ipython-input-201-ce6f8e091e1b>:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  slopes = np.abs(d(df["z"]))/np.sqrt(np.square(d(df["x"])) + np.square(d(df["y"])))
<ipython-input-201-ce6f8e091e1b>:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  slopes = np.abs(d(df["z"]))/np.sqrt(np.square(d(df["x"])) + np.square(d(df["y"])))


sol_numpy20  625.3554821014404 ms
maxGrad: 1246.4073209631038
Pair:
[            x         y         z
991  0.828510  0.016229  0.893811
240  0.828521  0.016840  0.131971]

Order: 4
10000


<ipython-input-201-ce6f8e091e1b>:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  slopes = np.abs(d(df["z"]))/np.sqrt(np.square(d(df["x"])) + np.square(d(df["y"])))


sol_numpy20  12746.904850006104 ms
maxGrad: 4346.72025021119
Pair:
[             x         y         z
3751  0.538723  0.168160  0.131924
1063  0.538800  0.168028  0.798256]
```